# Gearman: troubles with first use

Tags: gearman

I tried to start with Gearman. After downloading and setting it, `gearman_version()` works. But, when I start server and try to init worker like so:

```
php myFileName.php &
```

I see the code:

[image]

And when I init the client, I see code too. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, open your file `myFileName.php` in a file editor and post it here with your question.

How could we know why your code is printing code if we do not see the code itself?

Comment: Do you have short open tags enabled in your php config?

Answer (score 0):

i don`t know why, but the examples from youtube was not correct in my case. The first scripts, which worked I get from http://php.net/manual/ru/gearman.examples-reverse-bg.php

Answer (score 0):

You likely have short open tags disabled on your install. Notice, running a php file that doesn't actually contain any PHP will just echo the contents of the file.

```
>$ echo 'hello' > text.php
>$ php text.php 
hello
>$
```

You can verify the setting for your install with the following

```
>$ php -i | grep "short_open_tag"
short_open_tag => On => On
```

If tags are `On` you're all set.